# Interfacing MSP430 FRAUNCHPAD with MAX30102

Tags: i2c, msp430

I'm trying to interface the [MAXIM MAX30102](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/sensor-interface/MAX30102.html) with the [MSP430FR5739](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR5739) using I2C protocol. I'm using pull-up resistors (4.7 KOhm) on SDA and SCL lines, using a [breakout board](https://www.amazon.it/ARCELI-frequenza-cardiaca-Ossigeno-Compatibile/dp/B07RDJLSHY/ref=pd_vtp_1/261-1844606-7840534?pd_rd_w=5QZD1&pf_rd_p=61bdc6bd-1d7d-4cfb-84f6-e671e6da9772&pf_rd_r=49F2FE3M08QVBCZFPRZ7&pd_rd_r=f1e4c000-9aad-4ceb-ad66-070f792546b0&pd_rd_wg=bHshH&pd_rd_i=B07RDJLSHY&psc=1). However, the code stucks in the "while conditions" when the master is waiting for STOP condition to be sent, for example. I can't actually understand why this happens, because it seems that the msp registers are working properly.

Here are the **main C file** I'm using

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include "I2C_master.h"
#include "MAX30102.h"

void conf_UART();
void conf_CLK();

//void delayMS(int msec);                                                                             // Definzione funzione per gestione TIMER al fine di ottenere delay in millisecondi basato su f SMCLK

void sendInt(unsigned int n);                                                                       // Definizione funzioni per comunicazione TX UART
void sendData(unsigned char c);
void sendFloat(float f);
void write_string(const char msg[]);
void send_string(unsigned volatile int adc);

const char newline[] = "\r\n";                                                                      // Stringhe di comunicazione
const char welcome[] = "Heart Rate monitor using MAX30102\r\n";
const char error[] = "Wrong Value!\r\n";


int i = 0;                                                                                          // Definizione variabili globali
//int msec = 0;

// Check for slave presence
uint8_t check_slave() {
  uint8_t err = 0;
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP | UCTR | UCTXSTT;
  while (UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTP);             // Wait for STOP condition to be sent

  if (_no_ack()) {                        // If slave NACK'd,
    err = 1;                              // set error
  }
  return err;
}

void main(void) {
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;               // Stop WDT

  // I2C pins
  P1SEL0 &= ~(BIT6 + BIT7);
  P1SEL1 |= BIT6 + BIT7;

  PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

  //__bis_SR_register(GIE);       // Attivazione Interrupt
  //__no_operation();             // Nop (per scopi di debug)

  conf_UART     ();             // UART
  conf_CLK      ();             // CLK
  _USCI_I2C_init();             // I2C

  write_string(welcome);        // Benvenuto!

  uint8_t err = 0;
  err |= check_slave();                   // Confirm MAX30102 is connected
  err |= setup();                         // Configure settings for MAX30102

  while(1) {
    err |= get_data();                    // Get data from the MAX30102
    get_BPM_avg();
    send_string(get_BPM_avg());               // Display heart rate
    __delay_cycles(2000000);                 // Delay so the I2C is not being spammed
    if (err) {
     write_string(error);
     while(1);
    }
  }
}

void conf_UART (void)
{
    UCA0CTL1   |=   UCSWRST;

    P2SEL1  |=   BIT0 + BIT1;               // P2.0 e P2.1 as RX and TX UART pins

    UCA0BRW      =   104;                   // Baud-Rate 9600 bps
    UCA0MCTLW    =   0x02531;               // UG pag. 491

    UCA0CTL1    |=  BIT7;                   // Clock on SMCLK
    UCA0CTL1   &=  ~UCSWRST;                // Starting UART

}

/*
 * Configurazione CLK per gestione periferiche/protocollo I2C -------------------------
*/

void conf_CLK (void)
{

     // Clock System Setup 16 MHz
    CSCTL0_H = CSKEY_H;                     // Unlock CS registers
    CSCTL1 = 0;                             // Clear DCO settings
    CSCTL1 |= DCORSEL | DCOFSEL_2;          // Set DCO to 16MHz

    // Set ACLK = XT1CLK, SMCLK = MCLK = DCO
    CSCTL2 = SELA__XT1CLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;
    CSCTL3 = DIVA_0 | DIVS_0 | DIVM_0;      // set all dividers to /1

    CSCTL0_H = 0;

}

/*
 * Configurazione funzioni per scrittura dati/stringhe sulla UART -----------------------
*/

void write_string(const char msg[]){                                // Scrittura STRIGA su UART
    int len = strlen(msg);                                          // Valutazione della lunghezza della stringa
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
        UCA0TXBUF = msg[i];
    }
}

void sendData(unsigned char c)                                      // Scrittura singolo DATO su UART
{
    while(!(UCA0IFG&UCTXIFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = c;
}

void sendInt(unsigned int n)                                        // Scrittura INTERO su UART
{
    int num[] = {10000,1000,100,10,1};
    int pos, posI = 0, cnt, i;

    if(n==0)
        sendData('0');
    else
    {
        for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
            posI = n >= num[i] ? i : posI;

        for (pos = posI; pos < 5; pos++)
        {
          cnt = 0;
          while (n >= num[pos]) {
            cnt++;
            n -= num[pos];
          }
          sendData(cnt+'0');
        }
    }

    while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = '\r';
    while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = '\n';

}

void sendFloat(float f)                                             // Scrittura dato in FLOAT su UART
{
    int fInteger, fIntegerFract;
    float fFract;

    if(f < 0)
    {
        sendData('-');
        f = -1*f;
    }

    fInteger = (int) f;
    fFract = f-fInteger;
    fFract = 100*fFract;
    fIntegerFract = (int) fFract;
    sendInt((unsigned int) fInteger);
    sendData('.');
    sendInt((unsigned int) fIntegerFract);

    /*                                                              // Sezione disattivata al fine di associare al dato stampato la relativa unità di misura
    while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = '\r';
    while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = '\n';
    */
}

void send_string(unsigned volatile int adc){
    unsigned volatile long i = 0;
    unsigned volatile long tmp = 0;
    unsigned volatile char c = 0x30;
    unsigned volatile long adcl = 0;
    adcl = (unsigned long)adc*(unsigned long)3525;
    for (i = 1000000; i >= 1000; i=i/10){
        while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));                        //attesa disponibilit? TX buffer
        tmp = adcl/i;
        c = (char)(tmp+0x30);
        adcl = adcl - i*tmp;
        UCA0TXBUF = c;                                      //stampa singolo carattere
    }
    while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = '.';
    for (i = 100; i >= 1; i=i/10){
        while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));                        //attesa disponibilit? TX buffer
        tmp = adcl/i;
        c = (char)(tmp+0x30);
        adcl = adcl - i*tmp;
        UCA0TXBUF = c;                                      //stampa singolo carattere
    }
    while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = '\r';
    while(!(UCTXIFG & UCA0IFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = '\n';
}
enter code here
```

And this is the **I2C_master C file** used:

```
#include "I2C_master.h"

void _USCI_I2C_init() {
       UCB0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
       UCB0CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3 | UCMST | UCSSEL__SMCLK | UCSYNC; // I2C master mode, SMCLK
       UCB0BRW = 160;                            // fSCL = SMCLK/160 = ~100kHz
       UCB0I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDR;                   // Slave Address
       UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Clear SW reset, resume operation
       UCB0IE |= UCNACKIE;
}


unsigned int _no_ack() {

  int err = 0;

  // Check NACK flag for ACK
  if (UCB0IFG & UCNACKIFG) {  // if UNACKIFG is set, master got NACK
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;       // Send STOP condition
    UCB0IFG &= ~UCNACKIFG;    // Clear NACK flag
    err = 1;                   // This means there was a NACK
  }

  return err;                  // 0: ACK received, 1: NACK received
}


unsigned int _transmit(const uint8_t *buf, unsigned int nbytes) {

  int err = 0;
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR | UCTXSTT;  // Send START condition

  // Wait for the start condition to be sent and until TX not busy
  while ((UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTT) && (UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0));

  err = _no_ack();

  // If no error and nonzero bytes to send, transmit the data
  while ((err == 0) && (nbytes > 0)) {
    UCB0TXBUF = *buf;  // add data to TXBUF
    while (UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0) {
      err = _no_ack();
      if (err != 1) {
        break;
      }
    }

    buf++;
    nbytes--;
  }

  return err;
}

unsigned int _receive(uint8_t *buf, unsigned int nbytes){

  int err = 0;

  UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCTR;    // Clear write bit
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;  // Send START condition

  // Wait for the start condition to be sent
  while (UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTT);

  // If there is only one byte to receive, send STOP
  // as soon as START has been sent
  if (nbytes == 1) {
      UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
  }

  err = _no_ack();  // Check for ACK

  /* If no error and bytes left to receive, receive the data */
  while ((err == 0) && (nbytes > 0)) {

    while (UCB0IFG & UCRXIFG0);

    *buf = UCB0RXBUF;  // Take data from RXBUF
    buf++;
    nbytes--;

    // If there is only one byte left to receive
    // send the stop condition
    if (nbytes == 1) {
        UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
    }
  }

  return err;
}
```

Finally, the **algorithm procedure**:

```
#include "MAX30102.h"

uint16_t data[DATA_SIZE];
uint8_t data_pointer = 0;

uint32_t DC_signal_avg = 0;
int16_t AC_signal_prev = 0;
int16_t AC_max = 0;
int16_t AC_min = 0;
int16_t AC_cycle_max = 0;
int16_t AC_cycle_min = 0;
uint8_t positive_edge = 0;
uint8_t negative_edge = 0;

uint16_t miliseconds = 0;
uint16_t rates[RATES_SIZE];
uint8_t rates_pointer = 0;

int16_t FIR_buf[32];
uint8_t FIR_pointer = 0;
static const uint16_t FIR_coeffs[12] = {172, 321, 579, 927, 1360, 1858, 2390, 2916, 3391, 3768, 4012, 4096};

uint8_t setup() {
  // Timer interrupt setup
  TA0CCTL0 = CCIE;                 // CCR0 interrupt enabled
  TA0CCR0 = 20000;                        // 1ms at 20MHz
  TA0CTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_1;      // SMCLK, upmode
  __bis_SR_register(GIE);

  uint8_t err = 0;

  // Soft reset
  uint8_t TX_buf0[2] = {0x09, 0x40};
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) TX_buf0, 2);

  // Poll for reset to clear
  uint8_t addr = 0x09;
  uint8_t RX_buf = 0x40;
  while (RX_buf == 0x40) {
    err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) &addr, 1);
    err |= _receive((uint8_t *) &RX_buf, 1);
    __delay_cycles(20000);
  }

  // 8 sample averaging, FIFO rollover, no free FIFO interrupt
  uint8_t TX_buf1[2] = {0x08, 0x70};
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) TX_buf1, 2);

  // Heart rate mode
  uint8_t TX_buf2[2] = {0x09, 0x02};
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) TX_buf2, 2);

  // ADC LSB 15.63pA, 800 samples/s, 118us LED pulse, 16 bit ADC resolution
  uint8_t TX_buf3[2] = {0x0A, 0x31};
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) TX_buf3, 2);

  // Red LED power level 6.2mA
  uint8_t TX_buf4[2] = {0x0C, 0x1F};
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) TX_buf4, 2);

  // Enable slot 1 (red led)
  uint8_t TX_buf5[2] = {0x11, 0x01};
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) TX_buf5, 2);
}

// Calc DC_signal_avg
void calc_DC_avg() {
  uint32_t sum = 0;
  uint16_t i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {
    sum += data[i];
  }
  DC_signal_avg = sum / DATA_SIZE;
}

// Calc and return BPM avg
uint16_t get_BPM_avg() {
  uint16_t sum = 0;
  uint8_t i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < RATES_SIZE; i++) {
    sum += rates[i];
  }
  //BPM_avg = sum / RATES_SIZE;
  return (sum / RATES_SIZE);
}


// Low Pass FIR Filter
int16_t lowpass_FIR_filter(int16_t signal) {
  FIR_buf[FIR_pointer] = signal;
  int32_t z = (int32_t)FIR_coeffs[11] * (int32_t)FIR_buf[(FIR_pointer - 11) & 0x1F];
  uint8_t i = 0;

  for (i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++) {
    z += (int32_t)FIR_coeffs[i] * (int32_t)(FIR_buf[(FIR_pointer - i) & 0x1F] + FIR_buf[(FIR_pointer - 22 + i) & 0x1F]);
  }

  FIR_pointer = (FIR_pointer + 1) % 32;

  return (z >> 15);
}

void process_sample(uint16_t sample) {
  int16_t AC_signal = lowpass_FIR_filter(sample - DC_signal_avg);

  // Rising edge
  if ((AC_signal_prev < 0) & (AC_signal >= 0)) {
    positive_edge = 1;
    negative_edge = 0;
    AC_min = AC_cycle_min;
    AC_cycle_min = 0;
    if ((AC_max - AC_min > 80) & (AC_max - AC_min < 1000)) {
      uint16_t BPM = 60000 / miliseconds;
      miliseconds = 0;
      if ((BPM > 20) & (BPM < 250)) {
        rates[rates_pointer] = BPM;
        rates_pointer = (rates_pointer + 1) % RATES_SIZE;
      }
    }
  }

  // Falling edge
  if ((AC_signal_prev > 0) & (AC_signal <= 0)) {
    positive_edge = 0;
    negative_edge = 1;
    AC_max = AC_cycle_max;
    AC_cycle_max = 0;
  }

  // Find max in positive cycle
  if (positive_edge & (AC_signal > AC_cycle_max)) {
    AC_cycle_max = AC_signal;
  }

  // Find min in positive cycle
  if (negative_edge & (AC_signal < AC_cycle_min)) {
    AC_cycle_min = AC_signal;
  }

  AC_signal_prev = AC_signal;
}

uint8_t get_data() {
  uint8_t err = 0;

  // Get read pointer
  uint8_t rd_ptr_addr = 0x06;
  uint8_t rd_prt;
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) &rd_ptr_addr, 1);
  err |= _receive((uint8_t *) &rd_prt, 1);

  // Get write pointer
  uint8_t wr_ptr_addr = 0x04;
  uint8_t wr_prt;
  err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) &wr_ptr_addr, 1);
  err |= _receive((uint8_t *) &wr_prt, 1);

  if (rd_prt != wr_prt) {
    int num_samples = wr_prt - rd_prt;
    if (num_samples < 0) {
      num_samples += FIFO_SIZE;
    }
    uint8_t data_addr = 0x07;
    uint8_t RX_buf[3];
    uint16_t data_pointer_temp = data_pointer;
    uint16_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_samples; i++) {
      err |= _transmit((const uint8_t *) &data_addr, 1);
      err |= _receive((uint8_t *) &RX_buf, 3);
      data[data_pointer] = RX_buf[0];
      data[data_pointer] <<= 8;
      data[data_pointer] += RX_buf[1];
      data[data_pointer] <<= 6;
      data[data_pointer] += (RX_buf[2] >> 2);
      data_pointer = (data_pointer + 1) % DATA_SIZE;
    }

    calc_DC_avg();
    uint16_t j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < num_samples; j++) {
      process_sample(data[data_pointer_temp]);
      data_pointer_temp = (data_pointer_temp + 1) % DATA_SIZE;
    }
  }
  return err;
}

// Timer
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__)
#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A(void)
#else
  void __attribute__ ((interrupt(TIMER0_A0_VECTOR))) Timer_A (void)
#endif
{
  miliseconds++;
}
```

Please I need help, thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Nice post and a good start on debugging. I wish I could help more but I am not familiar with that micro.

Comment: You might need a scope or logic analyzer to examine the lines and see what is actually going on.